# SQL statement IN condition returns wrong results

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison-operators

Oracle: 11g

I have the following (2) queries that evaluate the same data but returns different results.

Query 1:

```
SELECT P.PLANT_CODE, 
                      P.DESCRIPTION AS PLANT_DESC, 
                      E.EMP_ID, 
                      E.DIVISION_CODE, 
                      M.MODULE_CODE, 
                      C.COURSE_CODE 
            FROM PLANT P, 
                     EMPLOYEE E, 
                     COURSES C, 
                     MODULES_REVISION M, 
                     TEMP_QUAL_SAVED_RESULT TQSR 
         WHERE E.PLANT_CODE = P.PLANT_CODE 
             AND TQSR.EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID 
             AND TQSR.COURSE_CODE = C.COURSE_CODE 
             AND TQSR.MODULE_CODE = M.MODULE_CODE 
             AND M.CURRENT_REVISION = 'Y' 
             AND C.COURSE_STATUS = 'A' 
             AND TQSR.EMP_STATUS = 'A' 
             AND E.PLANT_CODE IN ('002088', '002096', '002105', '009247') 
             AND M.MODULE_STATUS = 'A' 
             AND E.DIVISION_CODE IN (SELECT UD.DIVISION_CODE FROM USER_DIVISION UD WHERE UD.USER_ID = 'GMD-AD-02') 
             AND QUAL_TYPE = 'M' 
     ORDER BY P.PLANT_CODE,E.EMP_ID,M.MODULE_CODE,C.COURSE_CODE;
```

[image]
Query : 2

```
SELECT P.PLANT_CODE, 
                      P.DESCRIPTION AS PLANT_DESC, 
                      E.EMP_ID, 
                      E.DIVISION_CODE, 
                      M.MODULE_CODE, 
                      C.COURSE_CODE 
            FROM PLANT P, 
                     EMPLOYEE E, 
                     COURSES C, 
                     MODULES_REVISION M, 
                     TEMP_QUAL_SAVED_RESULT TQSR 
         WHERE E.PLANT_CODE = P.PLANT_CODE 
             AND TQSR.EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID 
             AND TQSR.COURSE_CODE = C.COURSE_CODE 
             AND TQSR.MODULE_CODE = M.MODULE_CODE 
             AND M.CURRENT_REVISION = 'Y' 
             AND C.COURSE_STATUS = 'A' 
             AND TQSR.EMP_STATUS = 'A' 
             AND E.PLANT_CODE IN ('002088', '002096', '002105', '009247') 
             AND M.MODULE_STATUS = 'A' 
             AND E.DIVISION_CODE IN ('UTN1','UNC1','BCU2','DEU6') 
             AND QUAL_TYPE = 'M' 
     ORDER BY P.PLANT_CODE,E.EMP_ID,M.MODULE_CODE,C.COURSE_CODE;
```

[image]

Query1 the results display the same value (009247) under plant_code column even though it brings employees for the other (3) columns.

Query2 the results display the correct value under the plant_code column for each employee.

1. Why is the Query1 displaying only one value under the plant_code even though it brings out employee another plant_code that are contained in ('002088', '002096', '002105', '009247') ?
2. Running the subquery "SELECT UD.DIVISION_CODE FROM USER_DIVISION UD WHERE UD.USER_ID = 'GMD-AD-02'" returns the values 'UTN1','UNC1','BCU2','DEU6' same as those from the division list.

**What is the difference when indicating the list of values vs using the select statement?**

Comment: Hi, the 90s called, they want their totally obsolete join style back

Comment: Can you show us the output of both the queries?

Comment: You are confusing pant_code `(002088', '002096', '002105', '009247')` and division_code `('UTN1','UNC1','BCU2','DEU6')`

Comment: @JohnHC . . . You are being unfair to the1990s -- at least that decade introduced the standard JOIN syntax.  I think the call is from the 1980s.

Comment: Your sub-select and IN lists will have different values.  Re-verify.

Comment: @unleashed The sub-select when run separetly returns the same values as in the IN list. Is weird that they do not return the results equally thought there is something different when building the query statement.

Comment: @JohnHC A join was not used since the where condition of the division code is not always applied it depends if a user has division restriction and the query statment is build in Oracle by forming a string and then executing.

Comment: @Teja Can't upload all the information since its a huge file but if you noticed that for both results is for the same employee and the same division but the plant code is incorrect, for the second result it displays the correct plant code.

Comment: @Angie comma tables and a where is the same as an `inner join`, but legacy. Info [here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) based on SQL server, but the same applies to Oracle

Comment: @JohnHC I will try this approach and review the results. Thank You!

Comment: @Angie Your sub-select is the only difference and therefore it must be returning something different.  You say what it is returning, but are there leading or trailing spaces on the values?